# R - for loop to get the row with the highest mean

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to use a for loop to find the row with the highest average expression over all samples of a particular dataset. I've already done this using an apply function, but have been told to find the solution using a for loop as well...

So far I can find the mean for each row, but it will only print out the means and won't return the maximum mean. The dataset contains thousands of rows so I can't just verify the result by eye.

So far the code I have to get the mean is:

```
>for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
+row <- df[i,]
+print(mean (df))
```

I've already tried using max or which to see if that would give me an answer but neither did.

I'm reasonably new to R so thanks for any help!

Comment: How about using `which.max(rowMeans(df))`

Comment: Why do you need a for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to stick to a for loop you could change your code to this:

```
  RowMeans = c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    RowMeans= c(RowMeans,mean(df[i,]))
  }
  print(paste("Row",which(RowMeans == max(RowMeans)),"has the largest mean it is:",max(RowMeans)))
```

otherwise I'd recommend you to use the solution posted above

Comment: If that was the answer to your question, can you mark it as valid?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `rowMeans` to get the `mean` of each row, and wrap it with `which.max` to find the index of the maximum value

```
which.max(rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE))
```

If we need the `max` `mean`

```
max(rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE))
```